# When attempting to void a Hold on balanced payments that had been captured, why is the response a Hold with is_void == true?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, balanced-payments

When using the Balanced Payments ruby gem (https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby), and using the `Balanced::Hold#void` method on a `Balanced::Hold` instance that is captured, we are getting a `Balanced::Hold` back that has its `is_void` property set to `true`.

That doesn't seem to make sense... is this the desired functionality?

Here's the output from the rails console:
https://gist.github.com/3063419

I am not sure if this is desired functionality. Happy to log it as an issue if someone thinks this doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ah, it seems that the [Balanced](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby) client, in [lib/balanced/resources/hold.rb#L26](https://github.com/balanced/balanced-ruby/blob/1d33fd665a0790f698fd340f117d9198be4a1a50/lib/balanced/resources/hold.rb#L26) does not handle an exception thrown when `save` is invoked.

The proper fix would be:

```
def void
  self.is_void = true
  begin
     save
  rescue Balanced::Error
     self.is_void = false
     raise
  end
end
```

I'll file a github issue.